# Can't run LBFGS on R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to run the `lbfgs-algorithm` on `R`, but I always get something like this:

```
L-BFGS optimization terminated with status code = -1001 fx = -0.0119691
```

I experimented with different settings, but I keep getting the same result.

```
TI <- read.csv("Alphabet01-2000.csv", header = TRUE)
TIn <- TI[9:28]
relPreisBew <- TI[8]
x <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 20L)
i <- integer()
d=0
b=rep.int(0,20)
grad <- function(x, j = 90, n = 100){for(i in j:n)
{b <- b-as.vector(t(TIn[i,]), mode = "numeric")*relPreisBew[i,]/(cosh(sum(x*as.vector(t(TIn[i,]), mode="numeric"))))*cosh(sum(x*as.vector(t(TIn[i,]), mode = "numeric")))}; return(b)}
Profit <- function(x, j = 90, n = 100){for(i in j:n)
{d <- d-tanh(sum(x*as.vector(t(TIn[i,]), mode = "numeric")))*relPreisBew[i,]}; return(d)}
lbfgs.out <- lbfgs(Profit, grad, rep.int(0, 20))
```

I'm guessing the problem is the grad function returns `NaN`s for certain values. 
I tried to solve this problem with restrictions to `stepsize` and `max_iterations`, but with no success. The values in `relPreisBew` and `TIn` are between 0 and 1, these `data.frame`s are of length 2956. I tried to recreate the following algorithm: https://minerva-access.unimelb.edu.au/bitstream/handle/11343/51750/bitvai_cohn_day_trading.pdf?sequence=1
See pages 4-7.

**Question**

Is this a problem with my implementation or is it because of the function?

Comment: "the gradfunction returns nans for certain values" And how do you expect the optimizer to deal with that? You might need to use contraints (see package optimx).

Answer (score 0):

I think your code can be re-written as

```r
set.seed(1)
TIn         <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(2956 * 20), 2956, 20))
relPreisBew <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(2956 *  1), 2956,  1))

grad <- function(x, j = 90, n = 100){
  b <- numeric(20)
  for(i in j:n)
    b <- b - as.numeric(TIn[i,]) * relPreisBew[i,] / 
      cosh(sum(x * as.numeric(TIn[i,])))^2
  b
}
Profit <- function(x, j = 90, n = 100){
  d <- numeric(1)
  for(i in j:n)
    d <- d - tanh(sum(x * as.numeric(TIn[i,]))) * relPreisBew[i,]
  d
}

library(lbfgs)
lbfgs.out <- lbfgs(Profit, grad, numeric(20), invisible = 1)
lbfgs.out
#R> $value
#R> [1] -3.95898
#R> 
#R> $par
#R> [1] 0.6454434 0.4368204 0.8539061 0.7784060 1.2161234 0.9605967 1.1229975 0.3174475 0.5408638 0.9498033 0.5697073 0.7133112 0.8297062 0.5387137
#R> [15] 0.3503997 0.4985034 0.8430027 0.3826048 0.9294685 0.9222503
#R> 
#R> $convergence
#R> [1] 0
```

This seems to work well for data between 0 and 1. Though, it is not too easy without the actual data to see if I get the same or what the issue is.

> I'm guessing the problem is the gradient function returns `NaN`s for certain values.

I do not see how this can happen unless it is related to the data. If I recall correctly, `cosh` cannot return anything less than 1 so the numerator in the gradient never become zero.

> I tried to solve this problem with restrictions to `stepsize` and `max_iterations`, but with no success.

While changing `stepsize` might help, I am not sure what you expect from changing `max_iterations`.

> Is this a problem with my implementation or is it because of the function?

The data set I guess. But it is hard to know without the actual data.